# how to convert javascript code to C# for Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code that I made for my game in unity that I made with javascript and now I am trying to convert it into c#. I think i got it right for the most part but I am getting an error at `pauseGUI.enabled = false;`

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pause : TouchLogicV2  {
    bool pause = false;
    GUITexture pauseGUI;
    pauseGUI.enabled = false; 

    public override void OnTouchBegan()
    {
        if(pause==true){
            pause = false;
        }
        else {
            pause = true;
        } if(pause == true) {
            Time.timeScale = 0.0;
            pauseGUI.enabled = true;
        }
        else {
            Time.timeScale = 1.0;
            pauseGUI.enabled = false;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. That is C# code not java code. And Unity does not support java. Close-voting.

Comment: It was java . I have converted most of it from javascript to c# myself. but i am getting an error at the part that I explained above.

Comment: @HighScore, he said Javascript NOT Java. Unity supports Javascript. Post your Javascript code then I will convert it into C# for you.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: I got `Assets/Script/Pause.cs(7,30): error CS1519: Unexpected symbol false in class, struct, or interface member declaration`

Comment: So you get this error after the line `GUITexture pauseGUI;`? Which version of unity are you using - they [replaced GUITexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GuiTexture.html).

Comment: No after `pauseGUI.enabled = false;`

Comment: If you comment out **pauseGUI.enabled = false**, you will get 2 more errors. They usually don't show up until you fix the first one.

Answer (score 4):

The reason this isn't working is because you're trying to change the properties of your `GUITexture` in the wrong scope. You can only create and assign properties outside a method. Move the assignment of pauseGUI.enabled to a constructor, like so:

```
public Pause() {
    pauseGUI.enabled = true;
}
```

As Programmer points out, you can also do this within a `Start` method.

Secondly, and this is more of a style issue, you don't ever need to write `if(x == true)` - just write `if(x)` instead.

Comment: First of all, he is right by using OnTouchBegan because he is overriding a method from the class he's extending called TouchLogicV2. Secondly GUITexture has a variable property called enabled. Look up GUITexture  documentation online and you will see GUITexture.enabled that can be set to true or false.

Comment: @Programmer You're right - I knew he was overriding, I just didn't realize the TouchLogicV2 logic used an OnTouchBegan method.

Comment: That's ok. I had to google TouchLogicV2 to release that OnTouchBegan  function was declared there.

Answer (score 3):

There are **three** things **causing** *compiler* **error**.

1) **Line 7**  `pauseGUI.enabled = false;`

You can't set class property inside the class. You must do it inside a function that is inside the class.
For example:

```
void Start ()
{
        pauseGUI.enabled = false; 
}
```

You can do it inside your **OnTouchBegan()** function too.
You can also make a custom function you can call to enable your paugeGUI.

2) **Line 17** and **Line 21** will also cause error if you fix the first problem. These lines contains

```
Time.timeScale = 0.0; and Time.timeScale = 1.0;
```

It is causing error because **timeScale** is datatype of **float**. To fix it, you must add ***'F'*** at the end of each number you **assign** to ***timeScale***. It should look like this:

```
Time.timeScale = 0.0F;  and Time.timeScale = 1.0F;
```

Below is your whole fixed code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Pause : TouchLogicV2  {
    bool pause = false;
    GUITexture pauseGUI;
    //pauseGUI.enabled = false;  This must be done inside a function 

    public override void OnTouchBegan()
    {
        if(pause==true){
            pause = false;
        }
        else {
            pause = true;
        } if(pause == true) {
            Time.timeScale = 0.0F; //Must have F at the end of the number
            pauseGUI.enabled = true;
        }
        else {
            Time.timeScale = 1.0F; //Must have F at the end of the number
            pauseGUI.enabled = false; 
        }
    } 
}
```